# What are the URLs to read/write posts and get user information using Tumblr's API with OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, tumblr

The list of URLs to read/write posts and get user information when NOT using OAuth are located here:  http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

However, these clearly are incompatible with OAuth.  For example, I'd like to get user information for a user who has granted access using OAuth.  But, the URL for a non-OAuth request requires that I POST a username/password to the URL and I get an XML file of the user information in return.

What I want is to be able to GET or POST to a URL with an OAuth access key and receive that XML of user information.  I imagine someone most know the URLs to do this, since there are implementations of this on the web.  However, there is no documentation.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Also answered myself.  For the benefit of others:  URLs are the same as in the Tumblr API document for non-OAuth requests, only do not pass username, email and/or password.  Instead pass authorization key and secret.  The easiest way is to use a library (e.g., oauth-ruby) and then simply make the request using the library's functions, passing all arguments the API spec requires EXCEPT: username, email and/or password.

Comment: could u tell me how u got the username of the user who grant access ...i got the access token ..but unable to get the user details... iam using the ouath library...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

That is the link for Tumblr's OAuth API Documentation